# How to pass a js variable set on one page onto another js file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I feel like my title is a bit vague but I'm not sure how to put this into words exactly.

Lets say I have 2 pages, page1.php and page2.php, both respectively have a js file, page1.js and page2.js. In page1.js I make a var x = 1 and a function that increases x by 1 everytime I press a button I placed on page1.php. So I press the button once and x is 2, another press makes x 3 etc.

Now I submit the form that the button is in, the form has the action page2.php so it sends me to page2.php and now I need my variable x in page2.js. How is this done?

I looked into localstorage and couldn't figure it out that way. I'm not sure how to do this, I just need whatever x ended up as on page1.php in my page2.js file. Doesn't really matter if it's done through jQuery or pure JS.

EDIT1: So I've gotten somewhere, I think? I added this to page1.js:

```
localStorage.getItem('iamount', i);
localStorage.getItem('oamount', o);
```

I tried putting these as setItem but it made no difference

and this to page2.js:

```
var i = localStorage.getItem("iamount");
var o = localStorage.getItem("oamount");

console.log(i);
console.log(o);
```

Now i and o both show up in the console as 1. I can assure you i and o are actually increasing on page1 so why are they showing up as 1?

Comment: What's you're looking for is localstorage/sessionstorage

Comment: @RadonirinaMaminiaina Like I said i tried that but I could only figure out how to pass a string or an array, not a variable.

Comment: @Kevin Dijkstra: By using JSON.parse() and JSON.stringify() you can pretty much pass anything in localStorage. Given it to be available. An ancient alternative used to be window.name. Another option for you would be to send x inside a hidden input and write it back in page2.php

Comment: It's not recommanded but you can pass the variable into window object.
`window.your_variable = some_value`

Answer (score 0):

If you could use Ajax to submit the form you could inject the variable in the form, read it with PHP as $myvar = $_POST['myvar'] and write that in a  tag like

```html
<script> var myvar = <?php echo $myvar; ?>;</script>
```

But this seems clunky...

Answer (score 0):

You can try passing the variable through query string in url from page 1 and read that query string in page 2 to read that variable's value.

Answer (score -1):

Define that variable globally.

```
var x=1;
```

Give reference of page1.js in page2.js

page1.js will declare, and initialize x and increment on calling function, which will be read from the script declared in page2.js

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You can use 'export' and then 'import'.
[Export developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export)